# "Awarding a player double/triple points for slicing multiple fruits in quick succession"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm practicing what I'v learned so far by making a Fruit Ninja game, and I am wondering, how would I go about the logic for implementing a mechanic where if a player cuts multiple fruits very fast, point counter goes up x2, x3 etc... I don't even know how to approach the problem to then think about how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have just an idea, so I'll also give just some ideas.

What I would do is to keep track of the time since last fruit cut. I'm not familiar with unity, but I'm guessing that unity has some built in clock to keep track of time on every update.

Edit: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html seems to do the thing :)

Also I would keep some variable like 'multiplier' alive. On each update, check if the time since last fruit cut is longer than what you wish to call a streak. If so, set multiplier back to 1. When player cuts the fruit, set that time as the 'last fruit cut' time, increment players score according to the current multiplier and then the multiplier.

Hope that mindflow is of some help, good luck :)

Comment: You helped me so much! I realized I asked a question in sort of a selfish format where I want an answer that can only be useful to my thinking and I am sorry for that.. but you helped me out a lot! thanks!